# Python. Как использовать переменную экземпляра класса в дочернем классе

Tags: python, ооп, наследование

как правильно использовать переменную `q` экземпляра родительского класса `A` при вызове метода `internalFunction1` в дочернем классе `B`?
Гугл не помог, уже и методом тыка не получается.
Но если методы класса `B` перенести в метод класса `А`, то все работает.

```py
class A():
    def __init__(self, a,b):
        self.q = externalFunction(a,b)

    def internalFuction1(self, a, b)
        externalFunction(self.q, a, b)
class B(A):
    def internalFuction1(self, a, b):
        A.internalFuction1(???, a, b)  # ??? == super(B, self).A.q  ??
```

конкретный пример

```
class sqldb:
    def __init__(self, server_name, database):
        try:
            self.conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                                  'Server=' + server_name + ';'
                                  'Database=' + database + ';'                                               
                                  'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
        except Error as e:
            print(f"The error '{e}' occurred")
            # sys.exit()

    def exec_query(self, query):
        cursor = self.conn.cursor     #  <---error. Solution: need ()
        try:
            cursor.execute(query)
            self.conn.commit()
        except Error as e:
            print(f"The error '{e}' occurred")

class Client(sqldb):
    # sql table column names in order
    col_name = ['id', 'phone', 'operator_code', 'time_zone', 'tag']
    _cols ='('
    for _s in col_name: _cols += "'" + _s + "', "
    _cols = _cols[0:-2] + ') '

    def add(self, id, phone, operator_code, time_zone='+00:00', tag='NULL'):
        arr = sqldb.exec_read_query(???, 'Select * from Client where ' + Client.col_name[0] +
                                    "'= " + str(id) + ' or phone=' + str(phone))
        if len(arr) != 0:
            print('User with this id or phone already exists')
            return
        query = 'Insert into Client' + Client._cols + 'values ('
        query += str(id) + ", '" + str(phone) + "' ,'" + str(operator_code) + " ',' " + str(
            time_zone) + " ',' " + str(tag) + "' )"
        sqldb.exec_query(???, query)
```

При выполнении `client.add('3', '88885553535', '800', '+10:00', 'tax')` python ругается, что ожидался обязательный аргумент `query`, т.е. указанный он посчитал за `conn`.
Поясните, пожалуйста, почему Client наследуя sqldb не может передать/подставить автоматически значение conn. Как его вытащить?

Comment: Нет такого понятия как "переменная q экземпляра родительского класса". С кодом из вопроса в экземпляре класса B есть атрибут q доступный по `self.q`. Нет никакого другого `q` из родительского класса. Так что непонятно, чего вы хотите достичь. Покажите пример, где что-то не работает, в том смысле "вот есть классы, вот я создаю объекты, вот я вызываю метод и получаю то-то, а ожидаю то-то".

Comment: Дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понимаю, что вы хотите, но вот вам рабочий вариант первого кода:

```py
class A():
    def __init__(self, a,b):
        self.q = externalFunction(a, b)

    def internalFuction1(self, a, b):
        externalFunction(self.q, a, b)

class B(A):
    def internalFuction1(self, a, b):
        A.internalFuction1(self, a, b)

externalFunction = lambda *x: print(x)
b = B(1, 2)
b.internalFuction1(3, 4)
```

Вывод:

```
(1, 2)
(None, 3, 4)
```

Дело в том, что `A.internalFuction1` - это вызов метода не экземпляра класса, а самого класса, поэтому там `self` сам никакой не передастся, его нужно передать вручную. И да, `self.q` у экземпляра класса `B` есть точно так же, как у его родителя `A`.

Что там за странная `externalFunction`, которая один раз используется для вычисления результата, а второй раз для получения побочных эффектов - я не понял, но придумал пример, с которым этот код хотя бы не ругается.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Действительно, ошибок быть не может. Однако, я разобрал класс Client и включил его методы в класс sqldb. Всплыла другая ошибка. Я получал объект метода. Черт, насколько нужно быть внимательным после VS...  Решение нашел здесь.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45348210/builtin-function-or-method-object-has-no-attribute-execute-for-cursor-ececut

Comment: Исправил и дополнил код для наглядности. Мб кому пригодится.